# Revert Node from v17.4.0 to v16.13.0 for React-Native

Tags: node.js, react-native, version

With regards to Node for react-native, I want to revert back my node version to 16.13.0 but in my React-Native Info under Binaries, it still state that I'm using Node v17.4.0

```
info Fetching system and libraries information...
System:
    OS: macOS 12.2.1
    CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7660U CPU @ 2.50GHz
    Memory: 281.46 MB / 16.00 GB
    Shell: 5.8 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 17.4.0 - ~/apps/project1/node_modules/.bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.17 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 8.3.1 - /usr/local/opt/node@16/bin/npm
    Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.11.2 - /usr/local/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 21.2, iOS 15.2, macOS 12.1, tvOS 15.2, watchOS 8.3
    Android SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 2021.1 AI-211.7628.21.2111.8139111
    Xcode: 13.2.1/13C100 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 11.0.11 - /usr/bin/javac
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 17.0.2 => 17.0.2
    react-native: 0.67.2 => 0.67.2
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

I tried downgrading it already by brew or direct node installation but the node version still not changing and I still got this error because of not updating my node under my react-native project.

```
opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
```

I tried already a clean installation of Node but no luck, can someone please point or help me to fix this issue for React-Native and Node?

Thanks and regards

SOLVE

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by removing yarn.lock and package.lock and deleting the node_module folder. This process will reconfigure to the current downgraded version of the Nodejs, thanks again.